# Is it posible to play iPod songs using AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios4, avaudioplayer, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have a question that, Is it possible to get and play the iPod library songs / playlist using AVAudioPlayer instead of using MPMusicPlayer?

Thanks in advance,
Chandra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way i tried with is just copy the song from iPod library to your app then you can play. When you close then you can delete also those songs. But makes your app heavy in terms of size.  See [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472141/how-to-copy-songs-from-ipod-library-to-app-and-play-with-avaudioplayer).

Another way i found is using [AVPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/AVPlayer) of AVFoundation framework. This supports iPod library. For reference of AVPlayer you can [go to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7386726/how-to-start-next-a-song-or-recognized-that-a-song-is-finished-while-playing-with)