# How to start next a Song or recognized that a song is finished while playing with AVPlayer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avplayer, avqueueplayer

How can I start next song immediately with AVPlayer? I have collections of song selected from iPod Library in `MPMediaItemCollection`.

Now how can i use AVPlayer for lists of songs to be played one by one??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For answer to your first question, You can use Notification for the same as

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(songFinished:)
                                             name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification
                                           object:[yourAVPlayer currentItem]];

-(void)songFinished:(NSNotification *)notification
{
     //Do your next stuff here;
}
```