# Play MPMediaItem using OpenAL

Tags: ios, openal

Is there any way I can play the audio I have as MPMediaItem using OpenAL. Is it possible to convert MPMediaItem to a OpenAL playable format?

Comment: Is it possible to convert MPMediaItem to ALBuffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you can, you can get music data from an MPMediaItem and then you are free to do with it as you wish...on information on getting music data from an MPMediaItem refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472141/how-to-copy-songs-from-ipod-library-to-app-and-play-with-avaudioplayer/7472676#7472676) question

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Daniel. How do I get the song URL from the MPMediaItem?

Comment: U get the URL property of the mpmediaitem

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'm marking your post as the answer. 

NSURL *itemURL = [song valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];